# Joining multiple times from sample table

Tags: sql, join

I have a query that looks like this:

```
select a.id, b.score score2017, c.score score2018 
from table1 a
join table2 b
  on a.id=b.id and b.year=2017
join table2 c
  on a.id=c.id and c.year=2018
```

this returns many duplicates.  How should I construct such query?

Comment: You should delete the question.

Comment: What was the syntax error? This query looks valid.

Comment: Note, if there are duplicates in this query, there may be duplicates in your data. Or "duplicates" based on your query's filters. A `JOIN` results in duplicates if there are multiple rows that match your `JOIN` conditions.

Comment: What exactly does "duplicate" mean? What does "such a query" mean? You don't say what you want. Please read & act on [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

i just realized I had syntax error. never mind.

Answer (score 0):

Which table does `score2017` and `score2018` belongs to ?

```
SELECT a.id, b.score, c.score 
  FROM table1 a 
 INNER JOIN table2 b ON a.id = b.id AND b.year = 2017 
 INNER JOIN table c ON b.id = c.id AND c.year = 2018;
```

You join `table2 b` to `table1 a` and subsequently `table3 c` to `table2 b` in that order.

I might also identify `a.id` as `_id`, `b.score` as `_bScore`, `c.score` as `_cScore` for readability sake

Comment: Since there were only 2 tables involved, `INNER JOIN` from `c` to `b` might eliminate rows the OP wanted. Also, OP did alias `b.score` and `c.score'. If OP wants to select `score` by year from `table2` for each of the `id`s in `table1`, a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` would probably be more appropriate.